# Plone/Grok - In a product built using "zopeskel plone", can grok conflict with plone.directives?

Tags: plone, grok

I am trying to build a control panel following a tutorial on the Plone Documentation site.
http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/functionality/controlpanel.html

However, I started off creating the product with (from the src folder) ../bin/zopeskel plone my.product, instead of creating with the dexterity option.  I did select the easy option when it asked what mode I wanted and I did select yes when it asked if I wanted to create a GS Profile.

I made sure to include grok in configure.zcml

```
<include package="five.grok" />
```

After following the instructions, I try to run the quickinstall to install the product, but it gives me the error:

```
ImportError: No module named directives
```

referring to the line in the settings.py file of their tutorial

```
from plone.directives import form
```

I added plone.app.registry to the install_requires bit in the setup.py file, and I made sure to make the changes in the configure.zcml file to include 
Just for experimenting, I did add 'plone.app.dexterity' to the install_requires, but I still got the same error.

Is grok conflicting with plone.directives?  If so, how can I fix this or do I have to use deterity instead of plone as the option for creating products?
If grok is not conflicting, what could the problem be?

On a side note, the tutorial does appear to be for using dexterity to create the product, but I am not sure if that is what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a gist with a howto that I wrote for plone.org some time ago:

https://gist.github.com/tisto/4ef1f6c7b445faf6ad73

This is considered best practice these days. Using grok is not recommended any longer.

Comment: Thank you for your tutorial.  I was able to create the control panel I needed.

I'm guessing that grok was causing a conflict then.  Thanks again.

Comment: Not really a conflict, but the tutorial assumes plone.directives.form (which contains the grok directives) is installed, and that's no longer the case by default.